# How to map ctrl/p clear cache and refresh NERDTree root node?

Tags: vim, vimrc

How do I map `<leader>r` which clears CtrlP's cache and refreshes [NERDTree's](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) root directory?

Pseudo code, I have:

```
map <Leader>r :CtrlPClearCache<cr>g:NERDTreeMapRefreshRoot<cr>
```

`CtrlPClearCache` clears the cache, but I haven't found a command to refresh the root node of NERDTree, without being in a NERDTree window.

Answer (score 3):

### Refresh both CtrlP and NERDTree

I use a custom key map to refresh both `NERDTree` and `CtrlP`:

```
nmap <Leader>r :NERDTreeFocus<cr>R<c-w><c-p>:CtrlPClearCache<cr>
```

I've mapped it to <kbd>Leader</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, but you can map it to whatever you want.

---

**How it works:**

1. `:NERDTreeFocus<cr>` - Changes to the NERDTree window
2. `R` - Refreshes the root node
3. `<c-w><c-p>` - Goes back to the previously selected window
4. `:CtrlPClearCache<cr>` - Refreshes the CtrlP cache

---

<sup>**Note:** Only works with recursive map versions (i.e. map or nmap instead of noremap or nnoremap)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to focus the NERDTree window in order to refresh the root. This should do the trick:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :CtrlPClearCache<cr>call NERDTreeMapRefreshRoot()<cr>
function! NERDTreeMapRefreshRoot()
    if nerdtree#isTreeOpen()
        call nerdtree#putCursorInTreeWin()
        call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap('R')
        " Go back to previous window.
        wincmd p
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Is there no way to refresh the node tree without the NERDTree window/buffer opened?

Comment: You'd have to ask the plugin's author for a definitive answer (or go through the (quite complex) sources), but usually, there isn't, as most Vim commands operate on the current buffer only.